# Make timerjob runs on specific server?

Tags: powershell, timer-jobs

I have an already developed timer job that is running on front end servers, but I want to set it to run on application servers only.

Can I do this with PowerShell without modifying any code of the timer job?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution posted by Benny Doesnt work.
Enable disable atimer job with powershell enables/disables on all servers regardless of which server you execute the powershell commands.

The only way to do this is with development in the jobconstructor specify the server you want the job to run, maybe by reading it from the FARM property bag.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example of how to create a new Timer Job for a specific server.  Check out the very last code block.  It does require a new constructor for your Timer Job that accepts a servername as a parameter.

http://maraboustork.co.uk/2010/10/using-powershell-to-set-up-an-sptimerjob/

Answer (score 0):

If you have globally deployed your solution, it should be possible. Start by [**disable** the timer job](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607781.aspx) on the WFE:

```
Get-SPTimerJob custom-timer-job | Disable-SPTimerJob
```

Then, [**enable** the same timer job](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607892.aspx) on your application server:

```
Get-SPTimerJob custom-timer-job | Enable-SPTimerJob
```

To learn more on how to manage timer jobs in SharePoint, read the article [Use Windows PowerShell cmdlets to manage timer jobs in SharePoint 2013](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee906546.aspx).

Comment: this enables/disables in all servers.